# How to interpret the check in a method that illustrates the indexOf method of a list

Tags: java, list

Can someone explain the purpose of checking next == null if e == null is true?

And when e == null is false, why do we need to check whether e equals next?

The last question, why method checks whether e equals next but if true it return previousIndex? I thought that it return nextIndex.

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
      if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))
         return it.previousIndex();}
// Element not found
return -1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: By the way--this is really unclear programming, and you should not imitate this style in your own programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary operator here is used to do a `null`-safe equals-check.

Sometimes, when you don't control the content of the List it's necessary to do such checks because you can't use the `e.equals(obj)` when `e`is `null`.
Better would be if the List would not return `null`values.

To figure out we it does we can refactor it.

In the first step we replace the expression of the if statement by a method call.
Because we don't know what it does we call the method `foo`, we'll rename it later. It will return a `boolean` and takes two arguments of type `E` one for the `e` and one for the `it.next()`.

After the refactoring it looks something like:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
  for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
     if (foo(e, it.next())
        return it.previousIndex();}
 // Element not found
return -1;
}


public boolean foo(E e, E next) {
  // in the first step we take the expression as it is
  return e == null ? next == null : e.equals(next);
}
```

Then we split the `?:` operator into `if` `else` statements

```
public boolean foo(E e, E next) {
  if (e == null) 
      return next == null;
  else 
      return e.equals(next);
}
```

Now we see what it does. If the passed Element `e` is `null` it checks if `next` also is `null` and in this case it returns `true`, `false` otherwise.

If `e`itself is not `null` it compares `e` with `next` using the `equals` method of `E`.

So it's a null-safe or null-aware equals comparison.
We now after we know what it does we rename `foo` into something useful like `isEqual`

et voilà

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
     if (isEqual(e, it.next()))
        return it.previousIndex();}
    // Element not found
    return -1;
 }

// null safe equals check
public boolean isEqual(E e, E next) {
    if (e == null) 
        // when e is null check if next / it.next() is also null
        return next == null;
    else 
        // else compare left and right
        return e.equals(next);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may help if we pull the `?:` out of the if so we can look at it separately

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      boolean test = (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()) );
      if (test)
         return it.previousIndex();
   }
   // Element not found
   return -1;
}
```

Unpacking that one more stage, remember that `?:` is essentially an if/else:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      boolean test;
      if (e == null)
         test = ( it.next() == null );
      else 
         test = ( e.equals(it.next()) );
      if (test)
         return it.previousIndex();
   }
   // Element not found
   return -1;
}
```

I think you can probably now see what the code is actually doing -- if e is null it checks the values for `==` equality to null, but if e is not null and we can call `.equals()` safely it uses that comparison instead.

In case you're still confused, let's expand it one more time:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      boolean test;
      if (e == null) {
         if ( it.next() == null )
            return it.previousIndex;
      }
      else {
      {
         if  ( e.equals(it.next()) )
            return it.previousIndex;
      }
   }
   // Element not found
   return -1;
}
```

If you're used to it, the `?:` inline test is a lot more compact *and* actually clearer in many cases. If you aren't used to it, it's safer to start by spelling things out in detail and then rewrite it into the compact form once you know the logic does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `IF` runs as follows --- If `e == null` is true, then evaluate `it.next() == null` else evaluate `e.equals(it.next())`. The result of this evaluation will determine if the `IF` needs to branch into `then` (which does a `return`) or (if you had one) the `else`

Basically, an `if` needs a truthvalue to test. In your case, the truthvalue is coming from a ternary. There is nothing magical to it. HTH

Comment: that is all I said before, but make no sense to me. I don't understand about the previousIndex and why those boolen related to the return

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to know how the if statement worked (see your question).

Answer (score -1):

right, but I would write it like this

```
   for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
     if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next())) {
        return it.previousIndex();}
     } else {         
        return -1;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Make no differentce man. Can you tell me how the check in if relates to the return?

Comment: @PMH true, operationally there is no difference but as per code readability it does.

Comment: Ummm, you have written illegal Java.  Your `else` is not attached to an `if`.